# Enabling Developer Tools Access crashes Unity and Activity Monitor

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, jetbrains-ide, developer-tools, rider

I'm facing the Developer Tools problem since yesterday. I use

- Unity (several different versions, e.g. 2018.4.23),
- Jetbrains Rider (updated today to 2020.1.3, yesterday 2020.1.2)
- macOS Catalina 10.15.5

I was refactoring some stuff and Developer Tools asked me for the access: *Developer Tools Access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue. Enter your password to allow this...*

Since then, two things are happening.

1. **If Developer Tools Access is enabled** (also tried doing this through `sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable` command) nearly every time when I'm changing something in code, Unity stops working (loading wheel present) and I can't turn its application off. I tried using Activity Monitor, it doesn't show any activities. I can only see the loading wheel.

   I even tried killing the Unity process through `kill unitypid`, it "kills" the process since it's not present on the processes list, but I still can see it on my desktop, being just as down as before.

   Checking Unity logs, I can see it stops on:

   ```
   Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly

   custom-attrs.c:1250: (null) 
      assembly:/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2018.4.17f1/Unity.app/Contents/Managed/UnityEngine/UnityEngine.CoreModule.dll type:UnityException member:(null) signature:<none>

   Stacktrace:
   Native stacktrace:
       0   libmonobdwgc-2.0.dylib              0x00000001460b4976 mono_handle_native_crash + 242
   ```
2. **If Developer Tools Access is disabled**, the application asks me a few times to enable it. After pressing Cancel a few times, Unity crashes and turns off and gives me the ability to send log error to Apple with the exception:

   ```
   Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

   Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
   Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

   Application Specific Information:
   abort() called
   ```

Don't really know what to do. I tried updating Rider, Catalina, installing a new Unity version.

Update: I formatted the disk and installed Catalina again, it still doesn't work.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation, I've discovered the following repro:

- Create a custom attribute that derives from the `PropertyAttribute` that calls `AssetDatabase.FindAssets("somethingsomething")` in it's constructor.
- Create a class (in my case it derives from the `MonoBehaviour` class in order to be able to call the constructor because of the gameObject placed on the scene) that contains a field that has a custom attribute mentioned above.
- Add `FormerlySerializedAs` attribute to this field (e.g. during refactoring).
- Create a gameObject with your class attached.

This will result in a pop-up window with a message that I've mentioned in my question:

*Developer Tools Access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue. Enter your password to allow this...*

Example:

```
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using UnityEditor;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class CustomObjectPathAttribute : PropertyAttribute
    {    
        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public CustomObjectPathAttribute()
        {
            var guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("Resources");
        }
    }
```

---

```
using UnityEngine.Serialization;

[System.Serializable]
public class TestClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Path to the file.
    /// </summary>
    [FormerlySerializedAs("pathToFile")]
    [CustomObjectPath]
    public string pathToFile2 = string.Empty;
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<TestClass> testClasses;

    void Start()
    {
        testClasses = new List<TestClass>();
    }
}
```

Attach the `MyBehaviour` script to the gameObject placed on the scene. The issue will occur after project recompilation.

Using `AssetDatabase.FindAssets("Resources")` in the custom attribute's constructor works fine if there's no `FormerlySerializedAs` attribute attached to the field in the `TestClass`.

I've reported the bug to the Unity QA Team and they successfully reproduced the issue. Here's the link to the Unity Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/crash-when-using-assetdatabase-dot-findassets-in-a-custom-propertyattribute-and-when-formerlyserializedas-attribute-is-also-used

There's nothing more I can do at this point except of

- not refactoring my fields when they have custom property attributes
  attached,
- not using `AssetDatabase.FindAssets` in my property
  constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to me in 2019.3.x

It generally happens when I'm testing animations and making changes while in play mode.

Nothing short of a reboot will fix the issue.

Comment: Hi Zenas Prime, 
there's a unity issue tracker for this, I suppose. Unfortunately, the problem still occurs for some of the users.
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/macos-inconsistent-crash-in-objc-msgsend-when-previewing-animations-with-animator-window-open